# Difference between procedures/functions and objects in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: java, plsql, oracle10g

I just stumbled upon the concept of objects in PL/SQL and thus started pondering on what would be the difference between Oracle PL/SQL procedures/functions and objects. I need to know their functional difference.

PS: I am familiar with Java.

Comment: [The introduction doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjint.htm) is pretty thorough. What exactly is it you need clarifications on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FUNCTION** allows a value to return with the `RETURN` statement.

**PROCEDURE** has no such return value. However it is possible to return values by declaring the parameter as `OUT` rather than the default `IN`. There is also a `IN OUT`.

**OBJECT** in Oracle is some other concept and has nothing to do with PROCEDURE AND FUNCTION and is more like a class definition as you know it from Java. Though this comparison is a bit weak. There is some useful documentation on Oracle Objects, e.g. this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/obj_types.htm

**PACKAGE** Though you have not asked for it, it should be mentioned. A Oracle Package contains a collection of Functions and Procedures (and more). The Package consists of the declaration and the package body. What is defined in the Package declaration can be accessed from outside the rest is private.

Comment: Note that packages can have functions, procedures, variables, records, type and subtypes, exceptions (and probably other stuff I'm not thinking of offhand) defined in the package specification, which makes them visible to users of the package.